# SSIS Bids 2008 Error On OLE DB Command - Operand type clash: int is incompatible with date

Tags: ssis

I am implementing a SSIS package using Bids 2008 and encountering an error  Operand type clash: int is incompatible with date.

I have declared a variable date with datatype DateTime and value 01/01/2015

Not sure why I am getting this error as my stored procedure is configured to accept a date field

Here is what I am trying to do

1. Specifying the parameters

   [image]
2. Map variables and parameters

   [image]
3. Variable declaration

   [image]

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are you trying to pass the variable as parameter to **Execute SQL Task** or other component ? If so check the data type when you do parameter mapping. By default it will make the data type long.

Comment: Show screenshots of how you have created the variable and how you plugged it into your stored procedure.

Comment: Yes I am passing the parameter to the Execute SQL Task.

Comment: sure I shall paste the screenshots

Comment: Please find the post updated

Comment: I didnt have this problem in SQL 2012 but having it in BIDS Sql 2008

Comment: I get this error when I click columns or preview

Comment: Not an answer, but a workaround...  Can you try using variable of type String instead of a DateTime?  Make the date variable of type string and set the value to `2015-01-01`.  Execute DataFlow.   Does that work?

Comment: Tried it . Same error

Comment: In the Set Query Parameters, try changing your parameter names to "parameter0", "parameter1" and "parameter2".